# HTML won't let me use capital letters

Tags: html

I want to use this: http://academyoftumblr.tumblr.com/post/6213339878/sliding-dropdown-menu dropdown menu on my tumblr page, but the code won't let me use capital letters. How do I fix this?

Comment: Which code won't let you use capital letters? What happens when you enter capital letters?

Comment: Have you tried to use `text-transform: capitalize` in css? Or `text-transform: none`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not HTML it's CSS where you've defined text-tranform property

Remove `text-transform: Camelcase;` from the code and it will work.

> ul#drawers li h4 {margin: 0; padding: 0px; **text-transform: Camelcase;** font-size: 10px; text-align: center; background-color: #363835; background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0); -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out; -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out;
>   transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out;}

The bolded part should be removed.

Comment: you have a lot of text-transform properties there, I don't know what part of code should I look at but as I said you need to remove them to get proper results.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `text-transform: Camelcase;` statement that is changing the case of all its contents.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work.